# Necessitate the need?

Tags: redundancy

I was reading an article that stated that a certain weapon "necessitated the need for" more training. To me, this sounds incorrect, as "to necessitate" means "to cause something to be needed" (Cambridge dictionary); therefore, following it with "the need for" is redundant. However, I can find nothing to confirm this, and a Google search for "necessitate the need" comes back with many examples of published works and scholarly articles that use the phrase. Am I being overly pedantic?

Comment: It grates on my ears, too. And I believe that the many examples illustrate an erosion in editing standards more than anything else.

Comment: Should be something like "revealed the need for" rather than "necessitated the need for."

Comment: "necessitated additional training",

Comment: You could use "created the need" if that sounds better; it's generally a good principle not to use a long word when a shorter, more common one would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you are not being pedantic in the least.

Let's say "A growth in population necessitates the need for more houses".

How is the meaning any different from **"A growth in population necessitates more houses"**.

Or how about **"A need for more houses will arise from an increase in population".**

I suppose a need for something could be a necessary requirement to some purpose or other. For example the investment in a new machine by a manufacturer of widgets *necessitates a need* for a greater demand for widgets.

But this sort of semantic gymnastic is unlikely to serve any practical purpose. So for the most part the use of ***necessitate*** in juxtaposition with ***need*** is duplicatory.

Answer (score 0):

It's not incorrect because need is followed by 'for', which states that there is a need for y. Necessitated means to make (something) necessary as a result or consequence. 'Need for y' is that 'something' which was made necessary, in this case.

Or maybe you need to share the complete sentence for analysing the context.

Comment: Apologies; I have edited the original question to show the context. The quotation was about a type of weapon that "necessitated the need for" more training. In this case, I believe it was the additional training that was made necessary, not the need for it.

Comment: You can't necessitate a need. Its totally incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the context. Then it should be-              The weapon necessitated more training. But, I guess you already knew that :)